# How to redirect custom aspx page to mvc action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, nopcommerce

I have upgrade aspx project to mvc. Now some of my old customer calling url with .aspx page and they are getting 404(not found) in mvc project.

So now I have to redirect .aspx to mvc page.

Old URL

```
www.domain.com/bookshop/pc-58573-53-{product_name}.aspx
```

New URL

```
www.domain.com/{product_name}
```

I am thinking to do via routing mechanism of mvc. like once this type of url come then it should be call my custom mvc action and in string parameter i will get pc-58573-53-{product_name}.aspx

Can you please suggest a best way to do this with minimal code.

Comment: thanks @sachin for answer

Answer (score 1):

Just define an action with route `'bookshop/{pageName}'`

Here are examples for 2 scenarios using Route attribute:

**In case, you don't want the URL to change:**

```
[Route("bookshop/{pageName}")]
public ActionResult MyAction(string pageName)
{
   // add logic according to what you receive in pageName property
   return View();
}
```

**or, In case you want to Redirect to a new URL:**

```
[Route("bookshop/{pageName}")]
public ActionResult MyAction(string pageName)
{
   // Create and use a method to ExtractProductNameFromPageName
   string productName = ExtractProductNameFromPageName(pageName);
   return Response.Redirect("~/" + productName);
}
```

The parameter `'pageName'` here should catch the page name past `'bookshop/'`.

In case, you don't have route attribute mapping enabled, add code below in `RegisterRoutes` method of `RouteConfig.cs` file:

```
// enable mapping of routes defined using Route attribute on specific actions.
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Comment: I have Try this but no getting call in action. i have to define route anywhere?

Comment: @sachin, This will not work in this case, because here OP needs *301 multiple pages redirect* and attribute routing can not done that thing it self as per as i know!

Comment: @Div Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated answer to handle that scenario too.